# Java- How to set setToolTipText for JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to move the mouse over an image which was plotted on a JFrame using g2D.drawRenderedImag and display the x, y of that pixel at the tooltip text right next to mouse cursor. i.e:

```
Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
g2D.drawRenderedImage...
```

I know how to read the x,y but don't know how to set setToolTipText for a JFrame. Can you guys help me please? I mean I can not do like this 
     **JFrame.setToolTipText** !!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since `JFrame` doesn't inherit from `JComponent`, it doesn't have `setToolTipText` method. Try getting `JLayeredPan`e from `JFrame` and invoke it's tooltip method:

```
getLayeredPane().setToolTipText("text");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do componentName.setToolTipText("context"); for more information, you can check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html lots of useful information about the Swing API

I see now you want to do it for a JFrame not a component, this works for a JFrame's title, maybe it helps

```
 import darrylbu.util.SwingUtils;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTitleToolTip {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            new FrameTitleToolTip().makeUI();
         }
      });
   }

   public void makeUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      for (JComponent component : SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JComponent.class,
            frame)) {
         if (component.getClass().getName().contains("MetalTitlePane")) {
            component.setToolTipText("Tooltip for frame title bar");
            break;
         }
      }
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: darrylbu.util.SwingUtils ??

Answer (score 2):

You need to take advantage of the `getToolTip` methods provided by `JComponent`

- [getToolTipText(MouseEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipText(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))
- [getToolTipTextLocation(MouseEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipLocation(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))

You will also need to register with the `ToolTipManager`, either by calling `setToolTipText` on your component with a non `null` value, or using [ToolTipManager#registerComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#registerComponent(javax.swing.JComponent))

**Updated with example**

You seem to be saying that you're rendering directly to a `JFrame`, presumably by overriding the `paint` method.  This is highly unrecommended, apart from anything, top level containers aren't double buffered, so you're going to end up with the possibility of flickering when you update the screen contents.

Much better to use something like `JPanel`, which is double buffered AND has the benefit of doing the work for you (when it comes to something like displaying tool tips).  It also makes your component more portable and re-usable

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestToolTipImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestToolTipImage();
    }

    public TestToolTipImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImagePane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/TestToolTipImage.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {

            String text = super.getToolTipText(event);

            if (img != null) {

                int xOffset = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int yOffset = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(xOffset, yOffset, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());

                if (bounds.contains(event.getPoint())) {

                    int x = event.getPoint().x - xOffset;
                    int y = event.getPoint().y - yOffset;
                    int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);                    
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(rgb & 0xffffff);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
                    sb.append("<html><table><tr><td>Pixel at ").
                                    append(x).append("x").append(y).
                                    append("</td>");
                    sb.append("<td bgcolor='#").append(hex).append("'>&nbsp;</td>");
                    sb.append("</tr></table><html>");

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    text = sb.toString();

                }

            }

            return text;

        }

        @Override
        public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent event) {
            return event.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as for getting the xy location have no issue, i just dont know how to activate tooltip in JFrame, if it was JPanel I would do JPanel.setToolTipText(.. but I dont know how to do it for JFrame

Comment: Why do you need it on the frame?

Comment: to render and display .drawRenderedImage

Comment: So, you can render a picture using a `JPanel` or `JComponent`, which will give you access to the underlying tooltip methods

Comment: even with the full path at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400)....  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: @DamirOlejar If the input is `null`, then Java can't find the resource you're trying to load - need to spend some time diagnosing the issue - start by varying the resource is available in the Jar by unzipping it and checking that the file is at the expected location

Comment: @DamirOlejar Oh,  by the way, if you're using my example, I'm using my own image stored in the root location of the Jar

Comment: @MadProgrammer, the input is not a null but a full path to an image (however, not in the root location of the jar file). Nothing urgent, just wanted to make a note, I have done a work-around. Thanks.