# Mouse-over pop-up in Java

Tags: java, swing, popup, mouseover, joptionpane

For an application I'm building in Java, I'm trying to get my program to display a pop-up message when certain objects are hovered over with the mouse. I know how to use `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` for knowing if the objects are being hovered over, but I don't know how to actually display the pop-up message itself.

I was thinking of using a `JOptionPane`, but have no idea how to close the pop-up without the user having to manually close it. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at [How to use tool tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Just checked it out, and since my objects aren't `JComponent`s, it's no dice.

Comment: What are they.............?

Comment: @MadProgrammer They were originally objects that extended `GRect` from the `acm` library, but then I changed them to extend `JComponent` to allow for the `setToolTipText` method to work. But now I can't figure out how to designate a certain area for the objects (i.e. an area which, if entered, will get the object's tool tip to display)

Comment: `JComponent` provides `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method, which should allow you to specify a custom tool tip for a given location. Try taking a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497757/java-how-to-set-settooltiptext-for-jframe/17497806#17497806)