# How do I make this an 'interactive image' [JAVA]

Tags: java, applet

I, basically, want to make an image a 'map'. Kind of like google maps, but with my own image. Here are a few of the issues I run into:

1.) Image is too large to fit into applet screen (Solution: click and drag to pan?)

2.) I have no clue how to make it so I can zoom in and out.

3.) I'd like to make it so when a person 'hovers' their mouse over a location, a text box shows up telling them about the area, but disappears when not 'hovering'

Here is my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class MapRender extends JApplet {

    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public MapRender() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("Mapv1Resize.PNG"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new MapRender());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This code is part of a sample provided by another area, I just changed it to an applet.

**Note**: I understand whoever helps me can't run the program without the picture, but you can substitute any 2k*2k resolution picture for this.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048)

Comment: Or something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171502/scroll-jscrollpane-by-dragging-mouse-java-swing/31173371#31173371)

Comment: The second example can accomplish the drag and move with mouse, but I'm sure the first shows the basic idea how you might achieve it without a scroll pane. The 3 option is basically a tooltip which supported by must components, you just need to take a little more control over it

Comment: Yes, the second is almost exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: My only big issue is the 'hover' thing I need to do. that's the crucial part.

Comment: Bascally, you can use `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` and `getToolTopTextLocation(MouseEvent)`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497757/java-how-to-set-settooltiptext-for-jframe/17497806#17497806)

Comment: Ok, so with that could I create odd shapes? this map is far from perfectly square.

Comment: Yep. Depending on what you want to achieve, the 2D Graphics API has a nice `Shape` API which can allow you to make very complex shapes

Comment: Awesome, because there are a LOT of territories to map out.

Comment: With the Second Answer you gave me, in line 15 keeps asking me for an identifier. Do you know why?

"catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)"

Comment: Are you using Java 7+?

Comment: That's a good question.... I think it's 8 but i'm on linux

Comment: Then it should support multi catch

Comment: Sorry about that just had to reinstall java. Thank you so much! Once this is all done I'll make sure to link you the finished project :)